# Comparing single word with array of QStrings

Tags: c++, qt

My code:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QString Vulgarisms[] = {"k****", "c****", "p******", "d*******", "j*******"}; // there is 5 QStrings in the array

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if((arg1.toLower() == Vulgars[i])
            ui->statusBar->showMessage("What is wrong with you?");
        else
            ui->statusBar->showMessage("");
    }
}
```

My problem is that comparison works only with the "d********" word.
I also tried to work with normal strings:

```
string Vulgarisms[5] = {"k****", "c****", "p******", "d*******", "j*******"};
```

I added the `arg1.toStdString().toLower()` method and it is not still working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that even after you find a match, you continue the loop.

That means if `arg1` matches the first string in the array (and you set the statusbar message) you then continue to check for the other words in the array, and `arg1` will not match any of those so the statusbar message will be cleared.

You need to `break` out of the loop once you find a match.

Comment: Thank you very much I do not know why I did not see the mistake.